# Why don't similar matrices have same eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

What is wrong with this proof:
Suppose R and T are similar operators and R has eigenvalue 2 for some eigenvector $v$. 
By property of similar matrices:

$R=STS^{-1}$

Therefore:

$Rv = STS^{-1}v$

$2v = STS^{-1}v$

$2S^{-1}v = TS^{-1}v$

$2S^{-1}Sv = Tv$

$2Iv = Tv$

$Tv = 2v$

Thus $v$ is also an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue 2.
Clearly this proof is incorrect, but where does it go wrong?

Comment: Protip: if you're wondering why a calculation fails to be valid, and you know of a counterexample, try evaluating each step using your counterexample, and pick the first line where the two sides fail to be equal. Then you know that this step is the problem, and often the counterexample will show you why the step was problematic. You can use this technique to defeat every $-1 = 1$ fake proof out there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you went from
$$
2S^{-1}v=TS^{-1}v
$$
to
$$
2S^{-1}Sv=Tv
$$
you completely ignored the rules of matrix multiplcation; you cannot arbitrarily commute matrices in a product! It should have read as follows:
$$
2S^{-1}vS=TS^{-1}vS
$$
Also not that it is not even clear that this is well defined as written, since $v$ is probably a column vector.

Answer (score 3):

Since the error in our OP Justin Sanders' argument has been thoroughly vetted in other answers, here I will *directly* address the title question.

Similar matrices *do* have the same eigenvalues, to wit:

if

$B = PAP^{-1}, \tag 1$

then

$B - \lambda I = PAP^{-1} - \lambda I = PAP^{-1} - \lambda PIP^{-1} = P(A - \lambda I)P^{-1}, \tag 2$

whence

$\det(B - \lambda I) = \det(P(A - \lambda I)P^{-1}) = \det(P) \det(A - \lambda I) \det (P^{-1}) = \det(A - \lambda I), \tag 3$

since $\det(P^{-1}) = (\det(P))^{-1}; \tag 4$

thus $A$ and $B$, having the same characteristic polynomials, also share the roots of these polynomials, i.e., their eigenvalues.

However, similar matrices do *not* in general share eigenvectors; if

$B \vec v = \lambda \vec v, \tag 5$

then

$PAP^{-1} \vec v = \lambda \vec v, \tag 6$

or

$AP^{-1} \vec v = \lambda P^{-1} \vec v, \tag 7$

that is, $P^{-1} \vec v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$; indeed, if $\lambda$ is a root of (3) of multiplicity one, then $P^{-1} \vec v$ is, up to a scale factor, *the* eigenvector of $A$ associated with $\lambda$.  Since we can in general choose $P$ so that $P^{-1} \vec v \ne \vec v$, the eigenvectors will not be shared 'twixt' $A$ and $B$.

So while the eigenvalues are similarity invariant, the eigenvectors transform according to $\vec v \mapsto P^{-1} \vec v$.

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong when you jump from $2S^{-1}v=TS^{-1}v$ to $2S^{-1}Sv=Tv$.